# Amazon Connect unable to Invoke Lambda function after permissions have been given

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-connect

I am attempting to use Amazon Connect to trigger a Lambda function.  I used the command line argument described in the Amazon Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-lambda-functions.html) and I am unable to determine why the lambda function is not being executed.  The role assigned has a basic execution policy and allows for connect to trigger the lambda function.  As for the code, I just have the code logging out the event at the moment, nothing really special.

Comment: If you run `aws lambda get-policy --function-name <FUNCTION-NAME>` from the AWS CLI, does it return a policy that includes an AWS:SourceArn that matches the arn of your Amazon Connect instance?

Comment: Yes it does.  it gives me the full JSON with the Action, Resource, SourceARN, and my account.

Comment: If you haven't already, enable logging on your Amazon Connect instance.  Then add a "Set Logging Behavior" step at the beginning of your contact flow.  Call into your contact flow and let it fail at the Lambda step.  Then check your CloudWatch logs.  Look for the message with `"ContactFlowModuleType": "InvokeExternalResource"` which is when your Lambda was called.  Paste the "Results" value from the CloudWatch log entry.  That may help us figure this out.

Comment: I tried to add logging for a the contact flow but this error came up: `An error occurred while providing Amazon Connect access to your S3 bucket for call recordings. Please make sure you have the appropriate permissions over the requested bucket, then try again. If the problem persists, please contact support for further assistance. JobId: ed5017e0-3bf2-4235-80ed-97160f9cb6bd`

Comment: It sounds like a permissions issue somewhere.  Without any screenshots or sample code and log files I don't know how else to help though.  You may need to call Amazon support so someone can actually see what you have configured.

Answer (score 0):

Use th command provided [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-lambda-functions.html) to set permission for your Amazon Connect instance to invoke the AWS Lambda function you created.  There should not be any need to access S3 from Amazon Connect in order to make an AWS Lambda function run.

If the AWS Lambda function itself is interacting with S3, then permission to the S3 resource should be granted via the IAM policy assigned to the AWS Lambda function itself.

Answer (score 0):

The reason connect is trying to access an S3 bucket is because you have Call Recording enabled. From the AWS console if you go to your connect instance (not the CCP) on the left side nav you will see "Data Storage", click that and disable call recordings and call reports. This does not solve the access issue, it just avoids it.

That should help you troubleshoot your lambda.

If you want to fix the S3 permissions, you may just want to use the "create a new s3 bucket form me" option in the Data Storage section of connect. This should setup the correct permissions, but if not you will need to write an IAM policy granting connect write access to your s3 bucket.